# The app crashes as soon as i make my button clickable inside dialog fragment

Tags: android, crash, modal-dialog, android-dialog, dismiss

Here is my code, if I remove the onclicklistener on button the app works just fine displaying the dialog I want to view. However as soon I make it clickable the app stops working.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogf, container,
            false);
    final Dialog dialog=getDialog();
    dialog.setTitle("DialogFragment Tutorial");
    Button button=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: reformat your code using `cntrl + k` so we can read it correctly

Comment: already did it @AJay

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the logcat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this `R.id.ok1` is in your layout `R.layout.dialogf` file.

Then in code you should use

`Button button=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ok1);`

**rootView** instead of **dialog**